# Content negotiation, send webp request to Symfony when webp file does not exist

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, content-negotiation

On Apache Httpd 2.4, I know that from a `.htaccess` file I can do this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.jpg$ $1.webp [T=image/webp]
```

in order to implement [content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) and for a jpg request, return a webp if the browser supports it.

Fine, I would like to send the request to Symfony when the webp file does not exists, so that a specific Symfony controller can create the webp version on demand, I know I could do this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.jpg$ $1.webp [T=image/webp]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp !-f
RewriteRule (.+)\.jpg$ index.php [PT]
```

but this sends to Symfony the original jpg request, is it somehow possible from `.htaccess` rewrite to send to Symfony the webp request instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp !-f
> RewriteRule (.+)\.jpg$ index.php [PT]
> ```
>
> but this sends to Symfony the original jpg request

Yes, but don't you need the original `.jpg` request in order to know how to generate the corresponding `.webp` image? The `.webp` URL-path is otherwise identical except for the file extension. You would then perform the same checks in your PHP code... you already know the `.webp` file does not exist, so you only need to check the `Accept` HTTP request header, generate the `.webp` image and serve it (or a 404 if there should be no image).

It's not possible to "rewrite" the request to webp and expect Symfony to pick this up without fundamentally altering the way Symfony checks the request. (Although I don't see why you would need to do this anyway, as mentioned above.)

You could perhaps pass a URL parameter to indicate to your script that a `.webp` image should be generated, but this does not negate the need for the same checks as above, so isn't really necessary. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule (.+)\.jpg$ index.php?generate-image=$1.webp [L]
```

The `generate-image` URL parameter then contains the document-root-relative (no slash prefix) URL-path of the `.webp` image to generate.

NB: You should be using the `L` flag on this rule, not `PT`. Your other rules should also include the `L` flag as well.